# Stop installable triggers if user removed permissions for the add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

How to stop all installable triggers of the add-on if the user removed permissions for the add-on in the page [Apps with access to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)?

For standalone scripts, the user will receive a ["Summary of failures for Google Apps Script"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#errors_in_triggers) email. But for the add-on developer, the add-on will just keep throwing the error "The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity." in Stackdriver Logging.

Notice that this case is different from uninstalling or disabling the add-on, as it would be possible to stop the trigger by testing the authMode of the event object. Example:

```
function onEditCustom(e) {
    if(e.authMode != ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL) return;

    // code...
}
```

Comment: You can and should be gating code that needs permissions with checks for that permission. For the specific error you mention, that message will no longer be logged by Google when it arises due to event object creation for simple triggers. Review the Apps Script issue tracker for specifics of the related bug.

Comment: It doesn't have to to with simple triggers, as it doesn't need permission to execute. And you were not clear at all.

Comment: The user will probably need to remove and re-install the add-on.  With no permission to do anything, no code can run.  If no code can run then there is no way to determine what the current state of authorization is.

Comment: @SandyGood I was thinking too that it should be the case: no code can run. Probably the errors I'm seeing has to do with add-ons that still has some permission, but not authorization to all services.

Comment: You could easily test what happens.  Install your own add-on under another Google account that you own, then remove the authorization from your account.  I'm not sure what happens, but if you find out, let us know.

Comment: @SandyGood It works just like you said: "With no permission to do anything, no code can run.". That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two outcomes for installable triggers if the user (creator of the trigger) remove permission for the script:

### [Standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) or [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script)

The owner of the trigger will receive an email from `apps-scripts-notifications@google.com` listing exceptions thrown by the script, and in the case of no permission, the message is: "Authorization is required to perform that action."

### [Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#add-ons)

As commented in the question, "*[With no permission to do anything, no code can run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786191/stop-installable-triggers-if-user-removed-permissions-for-the-add-on#comment88583503_50786191)*".

In addition to the comment, Google Apps Script documentation on [Installable Triggers - Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations), "*Add-ons do not automatically send the user an email when code run by an installable trigger throws an exception. It is up to the developer to check for and handle failure cases gracefully.*"